# what is the best way to raise an event from a native code to shared in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, event-handling

I am new to Xamarin forms and i would like to know how to raise an event from a native android service and use it to run code in the shared project

Comment: You could use DependencyService. The DependencyService class is a service locator that enables Xamarin.Forms applications to invoke native platform functionality from shared code. You could download the source code form the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I think the OP is interested about the opposite way: Native to Shared